# Setting Up Custom Font Size Using Textarea, Button and javascript

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am trying to set up some code, where the user can enter a number into a `<textartea>` and click a button, which will set the font  size of another `<textarea>` by editing the `Style`attribute. I tried the following:

```
<h2>Set Font</h2>
<textarea id='input'></textarea>
<button onclick ="myFunction()">Click</button>
<textarea id='MainText' style="font-size:18px;"></textarea>
<script>
function myFunction(){
  var InputValue = document.getElementById('input').value;
  document.getElementById('MainText').style.font-size = 'InputValue';
  alert('Font Size Changed to ${InputValue}')
}
```

I am not sure what to do.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

some syntax errors here.  You are using JS to do this so you need to camelCase `fontSize`.  Also, you are assigning it to a String when you should be assigning it to the variable name so get rid of those quotes. Also, you are interpolating the variable incorrectly in your alert:
`alert('Font Size Changed to ${InputValue}')`  You need to use backticks for this, not single quotes

```
var InputValue = document.getElementById('input').value;
document.getElementById('MainText').style.font-size = 'InputValue';
```

should be:

```
var inputValue = document.getElementById('input').value;
document.getElementById('MainText').style.fontSize = inputValue + 'px';
```

Comment: I don't get how I should add the alert.

Comment: @Coolsugar there are quotes ( " ), single quotes ( ' ), and back-ticks ( ` ) ...all 3 different things.  Quotes and single quotes can be used interchangeably but backticks have a special use-case for string-interpolating ( or called template literals ).  On a mac, it's the button to the left of the number 1 on the keyboard.   You can see more here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals

Answer (score 1):

you should use fontSize instead of font-size and inputValue as variable not string
e.g

```
document.getElementById('MainText').style.fontSize = inputValue + 'px';
```